# Can not get userID from facebook javascript login api

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap facebook plugin and facebook javascript api. here is my code

```
FB.init({
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    status: true,
    oauth :true,
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    //channelURL : 'www', // Channel File
    cookie: true, 
    //useCachedDialogs: false, 
    xfbml: true
});

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        alert(response.authResponse.userID); // literally shows three dots
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
            if (me.id) {
                alert(me.id);  // this works
            }
        });
    }
}, { scope: "email" });
```

I can get accessToken from authResponse.... its a long string. but the userID field is literally "...".  I can get the user's ID by making an extra round-trip to the server with another graph API call to fetch `/me` but that seems wasteful.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  Note that the oauth token is valid in the callback, but the userID field is literally "..."

Comment: are u not getting the userid by "response.authResponse.userID" statement ?

Comment: The question is not clear and I believe I have the same problem, so I'm going to clarify the question for the exact problem I'm seeing.

Comment: Seeing the same problem here. Glad to learn the token returned is legit, and that there's a workaround for now. Too bad to have to do the extra round trip though.

Comment: For me actually the userID is an empty string, "sig" and "secret" are both "...".

Answer (score 6):

[For the benefit of the OP] You can get the userID in the client by making an extra call to the server as you started to show.  Here's the correct code:

```
    FB.api('/me', function(me){
        if (me.id) {
            var facebook_userid = me.id;
            alert(facebook_userid);
        }
    });
```

This doesn't explain why the userID field is `"..."` in the login response object.  But it is a workaround.

Comment: How can I use this in html page. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a bug on github ( https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/151 ) because this seems a "feature" of the plugin. Not sure if the problem is in the facebook IOS sdk (not passing those data back from FB) or in the plugin (not passing those data back at JS level).

Comment: recently they moved the github project, and all the issues seem to have been wiped :(